# execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": , "message": "execution reverted" } }

Tags: ethereum, metamask, opensea

I want to buy an nft from Opensea. When I click the continue button.

```
execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x91b3e514", "message": "execution reverted" } }
```

I have balance in my wallet. I am using the Ethereum mainnet.

[image: Error Picture]

Answer (score 1):

just got the same problem. I think this is due to the small price

Comment: I appreciate your thinking. but instead of making an answer make the comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).